# Swapping elements efficiently in C++ vector

Tags: c++

Basically, I have a vector *vect*. I want to move part of *vect* from the end, to the start, efficiently. Example:

*vect* before = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

Moving the last two elements from end to start:

*vect* after = {6,7,1,2,3,4,5}

Now, I have the following function:

```
template <class ElementType>
void endToStart(std::vector<ElementType>& vect, size_t startPos)
{
   std::vector<ElementType> temp;

   temp.reserve(vect.size());

   for (auto i = startPos; i < vect.size(); ++i)
   {
      temp.push_back(vect[i]);
   }
   for (auto i = 0; i < startPos; ++i)
   {
      temp.push_back(vect[i]);
   }

   vect.swap(temp);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
#include <algorithm> // std::rotate
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    std::vector<int> vect = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    std::rotate(vect.begin(), vect.begin() + 5, vect.end());
    //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                     the new first position                              
    
    for(auto v : vect) std::cout << v << ' ';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vdh113P8P)

Comment: [That's a rotate!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZmeDQL4LaE&ab_channel=code_report)

Comment: @康桓瑋 :-D Indeed!